# Add driver to my server installation media?

Tags: wireless, drivers, server, system-installation, broadcom

I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 server on a machine via USB. The machine only has a wireless connection and needs the wl driver (proprietary Broadcom STA wireless driver). Without this driver, the network detection process of the installation fails.

On this machine, I can install Ubuntu desktop via USB by booting the USB, running the following commands, then running the installation program.

```
sudo mkdir /cdrom
sudo mount /dev/sdX1 /cdrom
sudo dpkg -i /cdrom/pool/main/d/dkms/dkms*
sudo dpkg -i /cdrom/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source*
```

However, there are two problems when I try to install from the Ubuntu 14.04 server USB:

1. The `dkms` and `bcmwl-kernel-source` packages are not included with the server ISO. This is not a big problem since I can add these to my USB.
2. There is no `dpkg` program in the server installation shell.

How can I get my server installation media to have the additional kernel module `wl`?

Comment: Have you tried using [Ubuntu Builder](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-builder) to add those three of these packages to the server iso? You can build your own server ISO with all of those packages, put the wireless driver .deb on the flash drive, and then install it with the server installation shell.

Comment: have you tried installing `linux-firmware-nonfree` package? `sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree`

Comment: @IanHyzy: The Ubuntu Builder has been [discontinued](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-builder/+announcement/12508).

Comment: @DuminduMahawela: There is no `apt-get` in the server installer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use gparted to make a smallish extra partition on the usb. Set up the live boot on the large partition, then use APTonCD to get the driver you need and put it on the smallish partition. Install your server, mount and install from the smallish partition, then off you go. [Ubuntu AptonCD Docs](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/APTonCD) –  Scott Goodgame 5 secs ago   edit